# Struggling with nested IF formulas in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Struggling to get this to work as I need. Basically a set of nested IF formulas with some conditions (see bottom of post for the rules)

I have 3 columns - J, K and L

- Column J
  contains the last login date (represented by 01/01/1970 if it's never been logged into)
- Column K contains the last interaction date (represented by 01/01/1970 if no interaction or blank if within the last 90 days)
- Column L contains the last activity date for a different metric. (blank if within the last 90 days)

I have another column, M - which I am intending to use as the calculated field.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

| J | K | L | M |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/1970 | 01/01/1970 |  | Recent Activity |
| 26/06/2021 |  |  | 26/06/2021 |
| 01/01/1970 |  | 01/02/2021 | Recent Activity |
| 30/06/2021 | 01/01/1970 | 23/03/2020 | 30/06/2021 |

So the rules are as follows:

- If Col J contains 01/01/1970 OR Col J date is before 25/03/2021 then check Col K.
- If Col K contains 01/01/1970 then check Col L. If Col K IS BLANK then show "Recent Activity"
- If Col L IS NOT BLANK then show Col L Date. If Col L IS BLANK then show "Recent Activity"
- If Cols J, K and L all contain a date, get the most recent date from them

I have pulled out a few tufts of hair trying to get this to work, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your rules, is 25/03/2021 a static date or should it be derived from a value somewhere? If static, then try this for the `IF` statements:

```
=arrayformula(if(J1:J<>"",if(isblank(J1:J)+isblank(K1:K)+isblank(L1:L)=0,if(K1:K>J1:J,if(L1:L>K1:K,L1:L,K1:K),if(L1:L>J1:J,L1:L,J1:J)),if(J1:J<datevalue("2021-03-25"),if(K1:K=datevalue("1970-01-01"),if(L1:L<>"",L1:L,"Recent Activity"),"Recent Activity"),J1:J)),))
```

[image]

There might be better functions, but this is mainly done with `IF()`.

`if(J1:J<>""` will run the subsequent formula as long as there are values in col J.

`if(isblank(J1:J)+isblank(K1:K)+isblank(L1:L)=0` checks each row to see if there is a date in col J, K and L.

If there is, then this gets the largest date (it's a bit clumsy but someone else might be able to help):

`if(K1:K>J1:J,if(L1:L>K1:K,L1:L,K1:K),if(L1:L>J1:J,L1:L,J1:J))`

An alternative to finding the largest date on each row could be:

```
transpose(dmax(transpose(J:L),{sequence(1,max(if(J:L<>"",row(J:J))))},{J:L}))
```

or:

```
query(transpose(query(transpose(J1:L),"select "&regexreplace(join("","Max(Col"&sequence(max(if(J:L<>"",row(J:J))))&"),"),",$",)&" ",0)),"select Col2",0)
```

The other IFs test out the other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

based on your rules try in row 1:

```
=INDEX(IF(ISDATE_STRICT(I:I)*ISDATE_STRICT(J:J)*ISDATE_STRICT(K:K), 
 VLOOKUP(ROW(I:I), SPLIT(SORT(FLATTEN(ROW(I:I)&" "&I:J), 1, ), " "), 2, ),
 IF(LEN(I:I&J:J&K:K), IF(I:I<"25/03/2021"*1, IF(J:J="01/01/1970"*1, 
 IF(((I:I="01/01/1970"*1)+(I:I<"25/03/2021"*1))*(J:J="01/01/1970"*1), 
 "Recent Activity", ), "Recent Activity"), I:I), )))
```

[image]

Comment: There's a circular dependency there somewhere

Comment: @SL8t7 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I think doing this as an arrayformula is unnecessarily complicated.

[Here is a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZXxFvrbU1HkWHr-pzQ9yC2jyLTv4hN2mDDhJjtHFYtw/edit#gid=1995169396) made specifically for this question.  In it, i placed this formula in cell M2 on a tab called MK.Idea and dragged it down:

```
=IF(J2,IF(J2>1*"25/3/21",J2,IFERROR(1/(1/MIN(N(K2),N(L2))),"Recent Activity")),)
```

Does it give the expected results? maybe you could add some more sample data on the sheet and test it out?